# django form errors before submit

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

My django form has errors in the initial page load, before the form even has a chance to be submitted.

My view:

```
def example_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # the request is GET
    else:
        form = MyForm(user=request.user)
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

return render_to_response('templates/example.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

Where I have my `pdb` imported, in the console I can see that my form already has errors. The output of `form.errors` in my console is all the fields in the model which are set to not null.

```
(Pdb) form.errors
{'example_field_1': [u'This field is required.'], 'example_field_2': [u'This field is required.']}
```

The `form` has not submit yet, but I am still getting errors. Can someone explain?

I'm using `django 1.4`.

My form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    _readonly_template = form.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget = _readonly_tempalte)

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        data = data or {}
        if 'user' in kwargs:
            user = kwargs['user']
            del kwargs['user']
            data.update({
                'first_name' : user.first_name,
            })

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

My model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    example_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    example_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Please post your form code

Comment: But you're explicitly putting `user` into the `data` parameter inside `__init__`, so naturally the form is now bound. Do you need to do that? Do you need to pass the user at all on GET?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The form prepopulates three fields for the user's convenience. So, binding data to a form automatically triggers the validation, which assigns a value to `errors`. Is there a way to prevent the validation on the initial page load? Or a different way to avoid this problem? I'd like to leave the prepopulated fields as they are.

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound) go into this in great detail. Triggering validation is quite literally what binding data to a form *does*; it simply doesn't make sense to ask for binding data without validation. I think perhaps you are mixing up data with initial; if you want to prepopulate fields, then you should use the `initial` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if still useful, but adding it here, as I just ran into this for my ChoiceField items within my form.

I was getting the same error messages, but eventually found out I had forgotten to ad 'or None' when initiating the form inside my view.

The initial code inside my view function that was displaying the error messages from the start:

```
form=FormName(request.POST)
```

I just added the 'or None' to it:

```
form=FormName(request.POST or None)
```

And all good after that.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/

accessing the form.errors attribute will trigger the various form validation methods. Those errors shouldn't show up when you render the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the user field is structured, but keep in mind that if you want the user name, you may want to change that from **request.user** to **request.user.username**.

I hope you resolved your issue, but in case you haven't, I had a similar issue which I was able to resolve by using "or None" when setting the form after checking if it is a POST (or GET) request.

In your case it looks like this may be a slightly different issue, but I wondered if this snippet might fix things up:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    # .. do stuff....
else:      #.....this is a GET
    data = {'user': request.user.username}   #note this is changed to username
    form = MyForm(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't you need to do something like this

```
form = NameForm(request.POST)
```

Rather then attempting to use the user object to populate the form? Will the user object have an example_field_1 in it?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: but you don't supply values for example_field_1 and don't mark it as optional so the errors are valid

Comment: Yes. But, wouldn't this be a concern for after the form is submitted, not before? If a field is required and there is no good default value, that seems like bad design to have it automatically error on the initial page load.

Answer (score -2):

This is the normal behavior.

Some properties of fields are checked on client side. The error messages belong to the form, are part of the html but are not displayed until needed. It saves a client-server request.